# How to get all constructors?

Tags: scala, macros

There is `ClassSymbolApi#primaryConstructor`, but I need every primary/secondary constructor that the class may contain. How do you do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> class A(x: Int) {
     |   def this(x: Double) = this(x.toInt)
     | }
defined class A

scala> typeOf[A].decls.filter(_.isConstructor)
res1: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(constructor A, constructor A)
```

Swap out `typeOf[A]` for a call to `ClassSymbolApi#toType`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `decls` includes constructors :)

Comment: One more quick question: what's the difference between `toType` and `typeSignature`? Both seem returning `Type` and I'm not sure which one to use in which case.

Comment: I have no idea. I think `toType` doesn't work for methods and the like whereas `typeSignature` does.